# In JavaScript, can a class A instantiate an object B that inherit from A

Tags: javascript, inheritance

In JavaScript, can a class `A` instantiate an object `B` that inherit from `A`?

Consider a class `A` that instantiate an object from a class `B`:

```
import B from "B.js"

export class A {
  constructor() {}
  fct() {
    this.b = new B();
  }
}
```

Can the class `B` inherit from class `A`?

```
import A from "A.js"

export class B extends A {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Note that I use Webpack with ES modules.

Comment: Have you tried it? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Why did you do this ?

Comment: You can but you should avoid it. It may cause a circular dependency issue and you may get a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can, but there is a huge risk of creating an infinite loop:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    console.log("I am A")
  }
  fct() {
    this.b = new B();
    // if you call fct here your browser will crash
    this.b.fct()
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log("I am B")
  }
}

let test = new B()
test.fct()
```