# With Webpack, can a class import a file that also import the first file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I try to write a class `A` that instantiate a class `B` that inherit from `A`. In JS, this is technically possible as shown on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/x4fjav5L/)  and with this previous question: [In JavaScript, can a class A instantiate an object B that inherit from A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76305181/in-javascript-can-a-class-a-instantiate-an-object-b-that-inherit-from-a)

With WebPack, I wrote the following files:

## index.js

```
import A from "./a.js";
let a = new A();
a.fct();
```

## a.js

```
import B from "./b.js"
    
export default class A {
  constructor() {}
  fct() {
    this.b = new B();
  }
}
```

## b.js

```
import A from "./a.js"
    
export default class B extends A {
  constructor() {}
}
```

When I try to run the above code, I've got the following error at runtime:

```
js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'A' before initialization
    at Module.default (a.js:3:56)
    at eval (b.js:3:32)
    at ./src/js/b.js (bundle.425598cf4c8e29cd2b4d.js:723:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.425598cf4c8e29cd2b4d.js:1278:41)
    at eval (a.js:5:63)
    at ./src/js/a.js (bundle.425598cf4c8e29cd2b4d.js:712:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.425598cf4c8e29cd2b4d.js:1278:41)
    at eval (index.js:2:63)
    at ./src/js/index.js (bundle.425598cf4c8e29cd2b4d.js:821:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.425598cf4c8e29cd2b4d.js:1278:41)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it an issue with Webpack?

Note that since I'm not sure I also reported an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/17239)

Comment: Circular dependencies are something you want to avoid.  In your case you could create another class say called Base, and extend both from this.   Alternatively just avoid classes altogether, Typescript & Interfaces make that part really easy.

Comment: This may be a legit edge case in Webpack, but generally speaking this isn't something you'd actually ever want to do in practice. If you stumbled on this in your own codebase I'd refactor it.

Comment: Live dangerously

Comment: @morganney I don't understand?!? I build my software architecture with knowledge. This is also why inheritance has been created!

Comment: If you intentionally build cycles into your apps architecture then you are living dangerously.

Comment: @morganney It's like recursive fonctions, I still don't see the problem

Comment: `I still don't see the problem`  There are plenty.  Even if webpack made it possible for this code to compile & run, there are other issues, like what is the bundler optimiser meant to do etc.  What if later you wanted to use this code in `node`, `vite` etc, they will all have there quirks when it comes to handling circular dependencies.   And is the reason why @morganney is saying `Live dangerously`.  Of course it is up to you, and you can totally ignore any advice given on SO.

Comment: "It's like recursive fonctions" It is decidedly *not* like recursive functions. Recursive functions run at runtime, with an execution context. Webpack **does not run your Javascript code at build time**, it is limited to what can be statically analyzed (i.e. what it can understand about your code *without* running it). "This is also why inheritance has been created" no, inheritance was created for subtype polymorphism not to enable circular dependencies. What does it even mean to say that A and B are subtypes of each other? If I were webpack this would be pretty low on my list of needed fixes.

Comment: @JaredSmith I work on nested HTML containers. My classes of type `A1`, `A2`, `A3`... are my containers. My classes `B` contains common methods related to all my containers. So  `A` inherits from `B`. `B` is a kind of super container. `A` and `B` are subtype.  Are you OK with that? My class `B` contains an `createAndAppend()` method (which is common to all my containers) that appends a new container to the current one. When I create a child container of type `A1`, `A2` or `A3`, I need to instantiate an `A` object which is a subtype of `B`. I finally copy the methods of `B` in all  `A` classes.